# Generators of a group

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

If we take the group $G={a,a^2,a^3,a^4,a^5,a^6=e}$, then number of generators will be $2$ as $1$ and $5$ are the positive integers less than and coprime to $6$. What are the generators?

It may be a very easy question. However, I don't know what the generators are. There's nothing in my book about it.

Comment: The question is unclear, since you seem like giving the answer. There are two generators $a$ and $a^5$.

Comment: I have got the answers from your comment.thanks

Comment: This is probably not helpful, but in general, for a group $G$, the meaning of the question "What are the generators of $G$?" is very unclear. So you are justified in being confused.